# Real and imaginary part of a complex sinusoid $y(t)=\sin(wt)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand the plots on [this page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/Analytic_Signals_Hilbert_Transform.html). It's a book about the Discrete Fourier Transform and it's discussing how a a function $x(t)=\cos(w_0t)$ or $y(t)=\sin(w_0t)$ is composed of a positive and a negative frequency component. I get why the spectrum of $\cos(wt)$ has two real components and none imaginary. But i don't get why $\sin(wt)$ have two imaginary components, as in **b)** of the following image.

[This is the link for the image, from the web mentioned page, that i don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zxXD.png)

I think i get how $x(t)=\cos(wt)$ is the sum of two complex sinusoids of frequencies of opposite signs that results in an zero imaginary part:

$$x(t)=\cos(wt)=\frac{e^{jwt}+e^{-jwt}}{2}$$
$$  x(t)=\frac{\cos(wt)+j\sin(wt)+\cos(-wt)+j\sin(-wt)}{2}  $$

Since 
$$\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$$

follows

$$  x(t)=\frac{\cos(wt)+j\sin(wt)+\cos(wt)-j\sin(wt)}{2}  $$

so

$$Re\{ \ x(t)\ \} = \frac{\cos(wt)+\cos(wt)}{2}=\cos(wt)$$

and

$$Im\{ \ x(t)\ \} = \frac{\sin(wt)-\sin(wt)}{2}=0$$

That explains why $\cos(wt)$ have two real parts on the graph, of same amplitude and "opposite" frequencies.

I will try to to the same with $\sin(wt)$:

$$y(t)=\sin(wt)=\frac{e^{jwt}-e^{-jwt}}{2j}$$

Using $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$

$$y(t)=\frac{ \cos(wt)+j\sin(wt) -(\cos(wt)+j\sin(-wt)) }{  2j  }$$
$$y(t)=\frac{ \cos(wt)+j\sin(wt) -\cos(wt)-j\sin(-wt) }{  2j  }$$

$$Re\{ \ y(t) \ \}=\frac{\cos(wt)-\cos(wt)}{2j}=0$$

$$Im\{ \ y(t) \ \}=\frac{\sin(wt)-\sin(-wt)}{2j}$$

I'm not sure how to follow from there. How come an imaginary part contains $j$? Or maybe $j$ should not be included? But in the case of

$$Im\{ \ y(t) \ \}=\frac{\sin(wt)-\sin(-wt)}{2}$$

Where that $j^-1$ went? This looks wrong to me because 
$$j \cdot Im\{ \ y(t) \ \}\neq\frac{\sin(wt)-\sin(-wt)}{2j}$$

What did I do wrong here? This looks so silly, I'm sorry.

Comment: You lose a minus sign early on, and then you pick the imaginary part (the coefft of $j$) when you are picking  the real part: check out your sums.

Comment: And if $w$ is real, it's clear that the real part  of $\sin wt$ is just, well, $\sin wt$.

Comment: Oh, i see. I've corrected the minus sign. It does reflect the plot where the sinusoid components have "opposite" amplitudes.
But i'm not sure a get what you said about picking the real part.
You're saying that actually what i've though was the $Re\{ \ y(t) \ \}$ and $Im\{ \ y(t) \ \}$ are both the real part of $y(t)$?

That makes sense, since $\cos(x)=\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Indeed it is strange to think that a difference in phase shift would make that change on the real and imaginary parts of the spectrum.

If that is the case, then is the book's image incorrect?

Comment: The real part is the part without $j$, for goodness sake get the $j$ out of the denominator, then collect together all the terms without $j$ and all those with $j$ and then you'll see that the real and imaginary parts are $\sin wt$ and $0$. I really can't see what your problem is: the real part of a real function is itself, so why go all round the houses to see this?

Comment: The image on the book (linked on the question) shows that $Im\{ \ Y(\omega) \ \}$ have two components at frequencies $\omega$ and $-\omega$ and opposite signs amplitudes. I was trying to get to that conclusion. Is the image incorrect? Should the lines in **b)** be on the $Re\{ \ Y(\omega) \ \}$ axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer is less complex than you are making it.
Once you have:
$$\cos(\omega t)=\frac{e^{j \omega t}+e^{j (-\omega) t}}{2} $$
that shows that there is a '$\frac{1}{2}$' magnitude at '$\omega$' and a '$\frac{1}{2}$' magnitude at '$-\omega$', both in the positive real direction.

Taking the same logic:
$$\sin(\omega t)=\frac{e^{j \omega t}-e^{j (-\omega) t}}{2j} $$
Multiply both numerator and denominator of the fraction by $\frac{j}{2}$:
$$\sin(\omega t)=\frac{j\frac{1}{2} e^{j \omega t} - j\frac{1}{2} e^{j (-\omega) t}}{\frac{1}{2}\times 2j^2}$$
Where $j^2=-1$. This eliminates the denominator and multiplies the numerator by $-1$:
$$\sin(\omega t)=-j\frac{1}{2} e^{j \omega t} + j\frac{1}{2} e^{j (-\omega) t}$$
This shows that there is a '$-\frac{1}{2}j$' point at '$\omega$' and a '$(+)\frac{1}{2}j$' point at '$-\omega$'. In this case, both are in the imaginary plane. The one at positive $\omega$ has a negative sense, and the one at negative $\omega$ has a positive sense.

Does that help?